# Magento: How to change order invoice pdf layout?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to change label positions of sales order [invoice pdf's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRumj.png) bottom total section. I have check app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php file but no luck. How can i change label positions?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the following files.

```
 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look into this files.